# How to remove this mini sticky view of code in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[I've done a lot of googling and I can't find any thing related to it, the results i keep finding are always related to the minimap on the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ270.png)

Whenever I scroll down, this mini preview of code is stuck at the top,
I hate it, it's so unnecessary. I don't remember how it got there, and I have no idea what it's called.

I've done a lot of googling and I can't find any thing related to it, the results i keep finding are always related to the minimap on the sidebar